# Google Sheet custom function returns 0

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-apps

I'm following [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/_cDze2eScOo/X-MxBeLXmRQJ) to count all the cells with a particular color.

in my case, `green/lime/#00ff00/rgb(0,255,0)`:

I've created my [own sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17VBC7VtEfCi0NPytfkFWGgS7aXpeTfM78xMGIboJ_Zg/edit?usp=sharing) and tried to recreate these custom function without success.

The issue is that regardless of how I try to manipulate the function or cells, the function always returns `0` instead of the expected count of `14`.

On its own `getColor()` works, but something seems to break down at the `ArrayFormulat(SUM())` stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing in the range as a string.. something like:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(--(getColor("C2:C15")=rgb(0,255,0))))
```

If you want to use your formula, try:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(N(getColor( ADDRESS( ROW(C2),COLUMN(C2) )&":"&ADDRESS( ROW(C15), COLUMN(C15))) = rgb(0,255,0) )))
```

Of course, the shortest way would be:

```
=countif(getColor("C2:C15"), "#00ff00")
```

All are working in [this copy of your spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FZzPu5Xb285k2s_XsCHcKp6bKWEW_aAdg4BhMXqAuWs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: thanks @JPV, unfortunately though it seems like it should that doesn't quite work. Though its not because of the `getColor()` function, but again because of the `ArrayFormula(sum(`. Would you try isolating the `getColor()` and then `ArrayFormula(sum(` in the links I gave to see what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question.

Using the `COUNTIF()` instead of the `SUM()` function was the key. `SUM()` works for numeric values whereas `COUNTIF()` can work with strings which is how the color values are represented.

So this:

`=ArrayFormula(COUNTIF( getColor(  ADDRESS( ROW(C2),COLUMN(C2) )&":"&ADDRESS( ROW(C38), COLUMN(C38))), "#00ff00" ) )`

instead of

`=ArrayFormula(SUM( getColor(  ADDRESS( ROW(C2),COLUMN(C2) )&":"&ADDRESS( ROW(C38), COLUMN(C38)))= rgb(0,255,0) ) )`